# java DateFormat gives weird format result

Tags: java, datetime

I use

```
java.text.DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date(0))
```

and get "3:00:00", though my timezone is UTC+04:00 (I live in Moscow, Russia).

No daylight saving is in effect. Why the result isn't "4:00:00"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Back in 1970, the time offset was UTC+3. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow_Time#Past_usage)

Comment: Thanks Friek, I understood it a bit later. The answer to the problem I had was `TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(0)`.